# Cannot write text as UTF-8 to file using python

Tags: python, parsing, encoding, file-io, utf-8

I am working on a program that reads a downloaded webpage (stored as 'something'.html) and parses it accordingly.  I am having some trouble getting the encoding and decoding correct for this program.  It's my understanding most webpages are encoded in ISO-8859-1 and I checked the response from this page and that is the charset I was given:

```
>>> print r.info()
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Sun, 20 Feb 2011 15:16:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.40 (Red Hat Linux)
X-Accel-Cache-Control: no-cache
```

However, in the meta tags of the page it declares 'utf-8' as it's encoding set:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

So, in python I've tried a number of approaches to read these pages, parse them, and write utf-8 including reading the file in normally and writing normally:

```
with open('../results/1.html','r') as f:                                   
    page = f.read()
...
with open('../parsed.txt','w') as f:
    for key in fieldD:
        f.write(key+'\t'+fieldD[key]+'\n')
```

I have tried explicitly telling the file which encoding to use during the read & write process:

```
with codecs.open('../results/1.html','r','utf-8') as f:                                
    page = f.read()
...
with codecs.open('../parsed.txt','w','utf-8') as f:                                  
    for key in fieldD:
        f.write(key+'\t'+fieldD[key]+'\n')
```

Explicitly telling the file to read from 'iso-8849-1' and write to 'utf-8':

```
with codecs.open('../results/1.html','r','iso_8859_1') as f:
    page = f.read()
...
with codecs.open('../parsed.txt','w','utf-8') as f:                        
    for key in fieldD:
        f.write(key+'\t'+fieldD[key]+'\n')
```

As well as all the permutations of these ideas, including writing as utf-16, encoding each string separately before they are added to the dictionary, and other erroneous ideas.  I'm not sure what the best approach here is.  It seems I've had the best luck not using ANY encoding because that at least will result in SOME text editors viewing the results correctly (emacs, textwrangler)

I've read through a couple posts on here regarding this topic and still can't seem to make heads or tails of what is going on.

Thanks.

Comment: [Your understanding is wrong.](http://www.w3.org/QA/2008/05/utf8-web-growth.html) The majority of web pages use UTF-8 by now. And even then, Windows codepage 1252 is a much safer bet than ISO 8859-1 thanks to oblivious authors.

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: Regardless of whether or not my understanding is wrong the response I got from this particular page indicated ISO-8859-1.  I'm not actually getting any errors, meaning that python will successfully write this to a file.  However, depending on what I use to view the file the characters may or may not display correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a problem with some of the things you're using to view the file. They will need to open it with the same character encoding you used to save it.

Comment: The first thing to do is to determine the actual encoding of the web page. Decoding it with ISO-8859-1 will succeed irrespective of the actual encoding, so don't bother. However it is very unlikely that a long-enough piece of data that's not encoded as UTF-8 will decode succcessfully. So, try `x = data.decode('utf8')` and tell us what happens. You could try decoding it with `cp1252` as well. Can you publish the URL?

Comment: Don't confuse "not actually getting any errors" with "working correctly". `utterly_random_gibberish.decode('ISO-8859-1')` cannot fail. Web pages lie about their encoding. Publish the URL!

Comment: Ok, I'm not really sure what your first comment was asking but I did tried data.decode and ` >>> x = open('../results/1.html').read().decode('utf-8') ` After some parsing ` >>> d
u'Iglesia Cat\xf3lica' ` I can't write d to a file, but I can encode it and write it.  However, that doesn't work either. The page has a dynamic ID attached to it but pages can be found here: http://213.97.164.119/ABSYS/abwebp.cgi/LLen-US/G0 >> general catalog >> set years to 1450 and 1550, first link, MARC format.  Should get you to the same page I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

I followed your instructions. The displayed page is **NOT** encoded in UTF-8; decoding using UTF-8 fails. According to an experimental character set detector that I muck about with occasionally, it is encoded in a Latin-based encoding ... one of ISO-8859-1, cp1252, and ISO-8859-15, and the language appears to be 'es' (Spanish) or 'fr' (French). According to me looking at it, it's Spanish. Firefox (View >>> view encoding) says it's ISO-8859-1.

So now what you need to do is experiment with what tools will display your saved files correctly. If you can't find one, you will need to transcode your files to UTF-8 i.e. data.decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8') and find a tool that displays UTF-8 correctly. Shouldn't be too hard. Firefox can nut out the encoding and display it correctly for just about any encoding that I've thrown at it.

Update after request for "intuition":

In your 3rd block of code, you include only the the input and the output, with "..." between. The input code should produce `unicode` objects OK. However in the output code, you use the `str` function (why???). Assuming that you still have `unicode` objects after the "...", applying `str()` to them would raise an exception if your system's default encoding is 'ascii' (as it should be) or silently mangle your data if it is 'utf8' (as it shouldn't be). Please publish (1) the contents of "..." (2) the result of doing `import sys; print sys.getdefaultencoding()` (3) what you "see" in the output file instead of the expected ó in "Iglesia Católica" -- is it `Ã³`? (4) the actual byte(s) in the file (use print repr(the data)) instead of the expected ó

**SOLVED** You say in a comment that you see `Iglesia Cat√É¬≥lica` ... note that there are FOUR characters displayed instead of the ONE expected. **This is symptomatic of encoding in UTF-8 twice.** The next puzzle was what was displaying those characters, two of which are not mapped in ISO-8859-1 nor cp1252. I tried the old DOS codepages cp437 and cp850, still used in Windows' Command Prompt window, but it didn't fit. koi8r wasn't going to fit either; it needs a Latin-based character set. Hmm what about macroman? Tada!! **You sent the doubly-encoded guff to stdout on your Mac Terminal.** See the demonstration below.

```
>>> from unicodedata import name
>>> oacute = u"\xf3"
>>> print name(oacute)
LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE
>>> guff = oacute.encode('utf8').decode('latin1').encode('utf8')
>>> guff
'\xc3\x83\xc2\xb3'
>>> for c in guff.decode('macroman'):
...     print name(c)
...
SQUARE ROOT
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
NOT SIGN
GREATER-THAN OR EQUAL TO
>>>
```

**Inspecting the saved file** I too saved the web page to a file (plus a directory containin *.jpg, a css file etc) -- using Firefox "save page as". Try this with your saved page and publish the results.

```
>>> data = open('g0.htm', 'rb').read()
>>> uc = data.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb7 in position 1130: invalid start byte
>>> pos = data.find("Iglesia Cat")
>>> data[pos:pos+20]
'Iglesia Cat\xf3lica</a>'
>>> # Looks like one of ISO-8859-1 and its cousins to me.
```

Note carefully: If your file is encoded in UTF-8, then reading it with the UTF-8 codec will produce unicode. If you don't mangle the data somehow when parsing, and write the parsed unicode with the UTF-8 codec, it will NOT be doubly encoded. You need to look carefully at your code for instances of "str" (remember the "typo"?), "unicode", "encode", "decode", "utf", "UTF", etc. Do you call a 3rd-party library to do the parsing? What do you see when you do `print repr(key), repr(field[key])` just before writing to the output file?

This is becoming tedious. Consider putting your code and saved page on the web somewhere we can look at it instead of guessing.

**32766.html:** I've just realised that you are the guy who had blown all his inodes trying to write too many files to a folder on a vfat file system (or something like that). So you are not doing a manual "save as". Please publish the code that you have used to "save" these files.

Comment: Right, I stated in my original post I suspected that it was encoded in ISO-8859-1 as that is what the server expressed the character set would be. However, what I am looking for is some intuition as to why when I decode the page using ISO-8859-1, parse it, encode it to UTF-8 and write it to a file junk is written to the file. You can see the third block of code in my original post is essentially what you are saying here in this answer but I've already tried that and for that particular attempt it doesn't matter what tool I use to display the file, all the foreign characters are junk. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake.  The `str()` is a typo.  The contents of ... are the whole program and of some length. All that happens in the text gets parsed. Default encoding is ascii. Using the scheme of opening in ISO-8859-1 and writing in UTF-8 produces the following: Iglesia Cat√É¬≥lica. `repr(data)=u'$a Iglesia Cat\xc3\xb3lica'`

Comment: Yes, this sounds reasonable. I think the miscommunication we're having is that I'm not accessing these pages off the web. I've saved them to my HD. So, could they have been saved in utf-8, then when I open them using ISO-8859-1 then re-encode them to utf-8 at the end I get these characters. It seems like what I want is the unicode string `u'$a Iglesia Cat\xf3lica'` which I can get by opening using `codecs.open('../results/1.html','r','utf-8')`. The thing is I have to explicitly give the write encoding also `codecs.open('../parsed.txt','w','utf-8')` and this produces `$a Iglesia Cat√≥lica`.

Comment: So, I've come to a resolution. It looks like what needed to happen was the file needed to be READ using utf-8 `codecs.open('../results/1.html','r','utf-8')` and WRITTEN using utf-16 `codecs.open('../parsed.txt','w','utf-16')` in order to be viewed properly.

Comment: Surely you jest. There is no indication at all so far that such a "resolution" would be valid. The web page is encoded in ISO-8859-1. You don't respond to questions like how you saved it to a file and what exactly you are writing as parsed output. Presuming that you are running Mac OS/X (you didn't contradict my assertion that you were sending your output to a Mac Terminal), what viewer tool are you using that requires its input to be encoded in UTF-16? Even on Windows, Notepad will handle UTF-8 ...

Comment: No joke. I used the same procedure but wrote using utf-8 and most of the text editors I used to view the documents didn't display the text properly (TextEdit, Excel, Word,...). Same thing writing using utf-16 all text editors view the results perfectly. The web pages were automatically saved using ScrapBook. What I'm writing out as parsed output is that table located in the center of the page parsed only using string slicing and regular expressions.  I'm not saying this makes any sense. My terminal is set to UTF-8 and I was able to print the output there with no problem.

Comment: (1) If ScrapBook (URL?) saves your web pages in UTF-8, then reading that as ISO-8859-1 and encoding the output as UTF-8 would of course cause the observed double encoding. (2) Observed behaviour of viewers: encoding the output as UTF-16 requires a BOM, which lets  viewers detect the encoding easily. Encoding as UTF-8 does not write a BOM by default and some viewers can't detect UTF-8 without that crutch. (3) Your terminal is set to UTF-8; how come the doubly-encoded UTF-8 was being treated as MacRoman? Anyway, you seem to have a solution that makes you happy. I hope I've been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> url = 'http://213.97.164.119/ABSYS/abwebp.cgi/X5104/ID31295/G0?ACC=DCT1'
>>> data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()[4016:4052]; data
'Iglesia+Cat%f3lica">Iglesia Cat\xf3lica'

>>> data.decode('latin-1')
u'Iglesia+Cat%f3lica">Iglesia Cat\xf3lica'

>>> data.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')
'Iglesia+Cat%f3lica">Iglesia Cat\xc3\xb3lica'
```

What do you get?